# Proof: Raising a complex number to a rational power

Tags: complex-analysis, exponentiation

The problem from the textbook is:

> Prove that if (a complex number) $z$ is a number on the unit circle, then $z$ has finitely many distinct powers $z^n$ if and only if the argument of $z$ is a rational multiple of $2 \pi$.

So I understand that $z$ raised to a rational argument $m/n$ can be viewed as trying to find the $n$ roots of $z^m$, which will give me $n$ answers. I also understand that the $n$ numbers $$ e^{i(\frac{\theta}{n}+ \frac{2k\pi}{n})} $$ are evenly spaced around the unit circle, with each successive pair separated by an angle of $$\frac{2\pi}{n}.$$

I'm basically confused about where the "if and only if" statement comes into play. Am I on the right track so far?

Comment: don't write $z^n$ ( as it is $\underbrace{z \times \ldots \times z}_{n}$ which is well-defined) but write $e^{n \log(z)}$ instead, which depends on the definition of the logarithm. so define the set of complex numbers $u$ such that $e^u = z$  (they are countably infinite all spaced by $2i k\pi$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$), apply $u \to e^{n u}$ to those, and see how many different complex numbers you get

Comment: Where does the problem even mention the operation of "raising a complex number to a rational power"? The sentence "$z$ has finitely many distinct powers $z^n$" means that the set $\{z^n\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}$ is finite, not what you mention in your question.

Answer (score 0):

We can write in the form $\;z=e^{it}\;,\;\;t\in\Bbb R\;$ , so

$$z^n=1\iff e^{int}=1\iff nt=2k\pi\;\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\iff t=\frac kn2\pi$$